# Why isnt my text bouncing in? CSS, HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am working on a project and im learning at the same time and so far everything has been working great!

But I want to be able to use the animated css code from Animate.css which should work in concert with the javascript in the wow.js file. Essentially, I need help troubleshooting why the animate.css code (e.g., wow animated bounceIn or wow animated fadeInUp) isn't working.

I would provide you with the files but Im not good with JSFiddle but here is the important parts.

html

```
    <header>
        <h2 class="wow animated bounceIn" data-wow-duration="700ms" data-wow-delay="100ms">Meet the Authors</h2>
    </header>
```

CSS

```
@-webkit-keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
    transform: scale(.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
    transform: scale(.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

@keyframes bounceIn {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(.3);
    -ms-transform: scale(.3);
    transform: scale(.3);
  }

  50% {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.05);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.05);
    transform: scale(1.05);
  }

  70% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
    -ms-transform: scale(.9);
    transform: scale(.9);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}

.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
}
```

I could provide the files if needed

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this .animated to your style like this:

```
.animated {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
       -moz-animation-duration: 1s;
         -o-animation-duration: 1s;
            animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
       -moz-animation-fill-mode: both;
         -o-animation-fill-mode: both;
            animation-fill-mode: both;
}
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/IA7medd/qv5L7osh/

Comment: I see what you mean but mine is still standing still

Answer (score 0):

To make your animation works, you have to add more than just declare the `animation-name`.

At least, you have to add a **duration** on it, like this :

```
.bounceIn {
  -webkit-animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-name: bounceIn;
  animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
}
```

[See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9cja5v7L/2/)